# embedded web server using FastCGI

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, fastcgi, hiawatha

I'm trying to create dynamic web control panel using [hiawatha web server](https://www.hiawatha-webserver.org) on embedded Linux platform.
I'm planning to split the web panel to 2 HTML frames:

1. One frame will be written as a static HTML.
2. Another frame will be generated using FastCGI - this frame will contain dynamic content.

Is it possible to do that? If yes, how?
I did not found into Hiawatha web server documentation how it is possible to configure the server to use FastCGI for specific frame.

Where can I find more information about embedded web servers design using FastCGI technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frames have been deprecated in HTML5, but you can still use iframes. In either case, you should be able to just name the `src` with the proper extension to trigger the FastCGI server.

If that doesn't work, then you can let FastCGI handle the main page and insert the static content as an iframe. You haven't indicated which language you are going to use for it.

An example in Perl would be

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print <<TOP;
<html>
<head>
<title>A Simple Perl CGI</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="static_content.html"></iframe>

## Perhaps some more html here
TOP

## use perl to print out your dynamic content

print <<END;
</body>
END

exit;
```